# Search not working for partial word and multiple word

Tags: 8, search

I am using search api and search api page modules to for search functionalities. Search works fine when I search for matching word. For example if I search keyword 'content', it works but when I search 'conte', it doesn't work. Moreover, if I search for 'content asdf', it doesn't work. However, it works when I perform same search using postman app. So, I guess it must be search api or search api page module. Any advices?

Thanks,

Pradip

Comment: Sounds like you might want to turn Stemming on, you can find an option for it in the Processors tab of your index

Comment: There was a bug that was recently fixed in Search API Solr - one of the conf files was not implementing edge ngram on full text searching properly. If you create the core with that conf file, then set the field to use Fulltext Edge N Gram in the search API admin, it should work.

Comment: See: https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr/issues/2896432

Comment: Oh, thats if you are using Solr, that is.

Comment: Hmm. I am using elastic search instance. 
@Clive: Stemming fixes partial search issue but I am still having issue with searching 'content asdf'. Any suggestions?

Comment: In that case, ElasticSearch has EdgeNGram as well so perhaps its the same issue affecting you. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html

Comment: But in your Search API admin UI, you _should_ have a dropdown on that field you are searching, and change it from String or Fulltext to Fulltext EdgeNGram.

Comment: I do have fulltext but don't find fulltext edgengram. I think it is not yet implemented in search api.